# Create charts using Microsoft Chart Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts, mschart

I download the samples from Microsoft in order to create charts in my MVC application using Microsoft Chart Control.

The problem is that all examples that I have found using Chart Controls in MVC are using images and lack interactivity if compared with Google Charts, HighCharts etc.

Am I missing something or this is the case? Can I create interactive charts using ASP.NET MVC and Microsoft Chart Controls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand (and used) MS Charts generate an image in the end. So, no. You won't have the same of sort of interactivity that highcharts, for instance, gives you. 
The interaction you might have is adding controls (checkboxes, dropdowns, etc) that will help manipulate data and regenerate the chart. Some also use imagemaps, but if interactivity/fancy animations is what you're looking for then I guess is not for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create interactivity using MVC 3 and Microsoft chart controls. I am doing it and it is working.

To add interactivity, you need to render an imageMap along with the chart image. Don't worry, it is not that difficult.

Please refer this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/DougLampe/archive/2011/01/23/charts-in-asp.net-mvc-2-with-drill-down.aspx)

In the view, use HTMLAction instead of html.RenderAction

```
 <img src="<%= Url.Action("Chart", new { id = Model.Id }) %>" usemap="#MyMap" />
 @Html.Action("ChartMap", new { id = Model.Id, name = "MyMap" });
```

Let me know in case you have any confusion.

Do not forget to mark as answer, if it solves your query.